# What causes a breakpoint to fail to bind?

Tags: f#, conways-game-of-life

**What causes a breakpoint to fail to bind?**

I receive an error when attempting to execute the following expression:

```
let grid_1 = {  grid with Four= grid |> update };; // Updated here
```

The error I receive is as follows:

[image]

**Code:**

```
type State = Alive | Dead 

type Response = | Survives
                | Dies
                | Resurected

type Grid = { Zero:State
              One:State
              Two:State
              Three:State
              Four:State // Central
              Five:State
              Six:State
              Seven:State
              Eight:State }

let isUnderPopulated (grid:Grid) =

    let zero =  if grid.Zero  = Alive then 1 else 0
    let one =   if grid.One   = Alive then 1 else 0
    let two =   if grid.Two   = Alive then 1 else 0
    let three = if grid.Three = Alive then 1 else 0
    let four =  if grid.Four  = Alive then 1 else 0
    let five =  if grid.Five  = Alive then 1 else 0
    let six =   if grid.Six   = Alive then 1 else 0
    let seven = if grid.Seven = Alive then 1 else 0
    let eight = if grid.Eight = Alive then 1 else 0

    let livingCount = zero + one + two + three + four + five + six + seven + eight
    livingCount < 2

let grid = { Zero =  Dead
             One =   Dead 
             Two =   Dead
             Three = Dead
             Four =  Dead
             Five =  Dead
             Six =   Dead
             Seven = Dead
             Eight = Dead }

let update (grid:Grid) =

    let underPopulated = grid |> isUnderPopulated 
    if underPopulated then Dead 
    else Alive

let grid_1 = {  grid with Four= grid |> update };; // Updated here
```

Comment: That doesn't answer your question but why don't you use arrays?

Comment: Because I don't know how to create a bounded array to only nine elements.

Comment: This is more of comment in general with regards to functional programming but since it has a signifigant touch point with what you are asking I will mention it. The more I use state with functional programming the more I need to use the debugger. The less I use state with functional programming the less I need to use a debugger. After a few months of functional programming and without using state I no longer needed a debugger. For a period of six months I never used a debugger with functional programming. It was only after using state again that I needed a debugger.

Comment: @ Guy Coder - Thanks. I am having issues with the Interactive Debugger. It keeps throwing these error dialogs at me.

Comment: So with functional programming when I had state and problems like you are encountering I took it mean that I should really rethink my design before spending time trying to figure out how to get the debugger to work in the same manner as with OO programming, or just drop in a quick printfn statement and be done with the impediment.

Comment: That's the thing... I don't know what it means to build a functional design. In the real world, things are stateful.

Comment: Yes things can be stateful, but the functions they use are not. One way around this is pass all the state that changes around in a parameter, which is typically named `env` or `world` in code. Typically `env` may start out as a few separate variables, but then you group them together into a tuple and name it `env`. Another way would be to code it OO, possibley C#, where you think with state, but then refactor it into functions using F#. Along the way you will see what really needs to be kept as state and what can be done to change your design.

Comment: As I noted for me seeking out problems that did not use state at first made it easier when I had to add state and the OO things like properties, members, interfaces, etc. The way I found problems that don't have state was to find functional programming books for other programming languages, e.g. ML, OCaml, Haskell, and translate those to F#.

Comment: But using the array code is much shorter and more human-readable. `let gridWithArray = Array.create 9 Dead` Then isUnderPopulated can be rewritten as: `let isUnderpopulated array value = (array |> Array.filter((=) Alive) |> Array.length) < value`

Comment: @ Froggy Finder - Wow, I didn't know arrays had that support. Thx! By the way, can you recommend any training material?

Comment: Regarding this specific question, were you running on release mode or something?

Comment: @Ringil - Nope. I was in debug mode.

Comment: it's usually some sort of optimization - and I only saw errors like this at runtime (the editor usually just refuses to bind the breakpoint and moves it to another line) -  sometimes if you use a C# Project it might not have compiled and so you lose the bindings and I think this is happening here - just try to **rebuild** the solution or your start-project and retry

Comment: about training material: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370273(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: My nickname is "Foggy" and not "Froggy" =)

Answer (score 1):

**You may be trying to bind a breakpoint to an application that is out-of-date, meaning that after changes have been made and before they have been recompiled.**

Try:

- Compile in Debug mode.
- Try to Clean Solution before setting the breakpoint.
- Go to the Debug folder, and delete [Your application].pdb file.
- Then do a Build or Rebuild your application.
- Go to the Debug folder and confirm you have a brand new [Your
  application].pdb file.
- Then try to set your break point.

**You may be not be generating Debug information or you may be in optimization mode which could have an effect on this.**

For C++ projects:

Check the following project properties:

- C++/General/Debug Information Format: Program Database.
- C++/Optimization: Disabled.
- C++/Code generation/Runtime library: Multi-threaded Debug.
- Linker/Debugging/Generate Debug Info: Yes.
- Linker/Debugging/Generate program database:
  $(TargetDir)$(TargetName).pdb.
- Linker/Manifest File/Generate Manifest: No.
- Linker/Manifest File/Allow Isolation: No.
- Linker/Embedded IDL/Ignore embedded IDL: Yes.

For C# projects check the following:

- In the projects properties set Build/General/Optimize code : Disabled.
- In the IDE settings Debug/Options/Debug/General Suppress JIT
  optimization on module load (Managed only): Enabled

**It may be a bug in your VS.**

Try opening your solution in another machines IDE.  If you can bind a breakpoint on a different machine this can mean that there is an issue with either your VS or your OS..

Check that your IDE is up-to-date:

There have been reports of issues like this in the VS2013 RTM as well as VS2015 Update 1 and Update2.

In VS go to Tools/Extensions & Updates/Updates/Product Updates and see what version you are running. If an update is needed it will appear there.

**It may be due to a bug in the OS.**

If your running a Win 10 OS, there was a reported bug regarding this issue which existed in build 14251. This was resolved in build 14257 (and above).